# how to json parse with components Separated By String

Tags: iphone, ios, json

im new to parsing JSON and im trying a simple task, to retrieve a URL from a forecast weather json file.

Here i parse the json and i NSLog the contents of each component of the data:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];

NSArray *data =  [res objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"data=%@",data);

NSArray *results =  [data valueForKey:@"weather"];
NSLog(@"weather=%@",results);

NSArray *results1 =  [results valueForKey:@"tempMaxC"];
NSLog(@"tempMaxC=%@",results1);

NSArray *results2 =  [results1 valueForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"];
NSLog(@"weatherIconUrl=%@",results2);
```

The problem is that when i get the WeatherIconUrl it comes with this format

```
"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
```

and i cant get the url itself without the quotation marks, i tried using nsrange and componentsSeparatedByString but it always gives me this error:

```
[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

JSON from server:

```
{
    "data": {
        "current_condition": [
            {
                "cloudcover": "0",
                "humidity": "73",
                "observation_time": "12:19 PM",
                "precipMM": "0.0",
                "pressure": "1021",
                "temp_C": "23",
                "temp_F": "73",
                "visibility": "10",
                "weatherCode": "113",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Sunny"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "NW",
                "winddirDegree": "320",
                "windspeedKmph": "17",
                "windspeedMiles": "11"
            }
        ],
        "request": [
            {
                "query": "Fanzeres, Portugal",
                "type": "City"
            }
        ],
        "weather": [
            {
                "date": "2012-09-12",
                "precipMM": "0.0",
                "tempMaxC": "28",
                "tempMaxF": "83",
                "tempMinC": "17",
                "tempMinF": "63",
                "weatherCode": "113",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Sunny"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "NW",
                "winddirDegree": "312",
                "winddirection": "NW",
                "windspeedKmph": "16",
                "windspeedMiles": "10"
            },
            {
                "date": "2012-09-13",
                "precipMM": "0.0",
                "tempMaxC": "33",
                "tempMaxF": "91",
                "tempMinC": "17",
                "tempMinF": "63",
                "weatherCode": "113",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Sunny"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "N",
                "winddirDegree": "8",
                "winddirection": "N",
                "windspeedKmph": "10",
                "windspeedMiles": "6"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english and please correct me if im doing this wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code where you are calling componentsSeparatedByString

Comment: Can you post the JSON result you retrieved from the server? Also you can't `componentsSeparatedByString:` on a `NSArray` object it a method of `NSString`.

Comment: Yeah, use a JSONParser, and don't call componentsSeparatedByString on an NSArray object, obviously it will crash, as the NSArray doesn't have any method called componentsSeparatedByString

Comment: Please post the response from the server. Also, how have you tested it to determine that the URL includes quotes?

Comment: this is the server response: http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Fanzeres&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=8c1537f84d183203122108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly have quotes surrounding your URL, then try something like this:

```
NSString *someURLString = [results2 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *quotesRemoved = [someURLString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];
```

Comment: this is the response from the server: http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Fanzeres&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=8c1537f84d183203122108          tried your method and got -[__NSArrayI stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.  thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Do you know how your json is structured? Then get the string you want to trim. I assumed the strings were in that array but they are somewhere else. I don't really understand how you set up your results arrays actually which makes it tough for me to tell you exactly what to do. But I don't see extra quotes in the json anyway. Could you explain how you verified the presence of these quotes?

Answer (score 3):

use objectForKey instead of valueForKey when getting the array from @"weatherIconUrl" then get the string into NSString e.g.

```
NSString *weatherIconUrlString = [results2 objectAtIndex:0]
```

to check that this is a valid url, use the canHandleRequest method of NSURLConnection, e.g.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weatherIconUrlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
BOOL canGo = [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request];
```

Comment: Got a null value with  [res objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"];       thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

putting the server's output through [jsonLint.com](http://jsonLint.com) gives an easier to read format of the json.

The code below now gets the weather icon url as required. It assumes the json has been downloaded as an NSData object called jsonData, and doesn't check for which date the data refers to.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDict      = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                                error:&error];
NSArray      *data          =  [jsonDict    valueForKey:@"data"];
NSArray      *weather       =  [data        valueForKey:@"weather"];
NSArray      *weatherIcon   = [[weather     objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"];
NSString     *url           = [[weatherIcon objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"value"];
```

The resulting url is used in an NSURLRequest and shown in a webview

[image]